# c# contains case insensitive search

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code

```
var returnData = DemoData.Books.AsQueryable();

if (criteria.Author != string.Empty)
{
    returnData = returnData.Where(x => x.Author.Contains(criteria.Author));
}
```

How do I made the where clause case insensitive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. You can use `ToLower()` function. `ToLower` changes strings to be all lowercase. It converts an entire string—without changing letters that are already lowercased or digits. It copies a string and returns a reference to the new string. So it is always better option to declare `criteria.Author.ToLower()` outside the query.

   ```
   string lowerAuthor = criteria.Author.ToLower();
   returnData = returnData.Where
           (x => x.Author.ToLower().Contains(lowerAuthor));
   ```
2. You could also use `IndexOf`overload with the `StringComparison` enum. It would give you better performance than `ToLower()`. The signature of this overload is:

   ```
   int string.IndexOf(string value, StringComparison comparisonType);
   ```

   ---

   ```
   returnData = returnData.Where
       (x => x.Author.IndexOf(criteria.Author, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1);
   ```

Comment: You should declare `criteria.Author.ToLower()` outside the query, to prevent unnecessary string allocation during every iteration (assuming it LINQ to Objects). Or even better - use `IndexOf` with  `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` which will allow you to skip `ToLower` completely.

Comment: with option 2, where are you saying compare it to x.Author?

Comment: @user2206329 I am searching the beginning index of the  `criteria.Author` inside the `x`. And `IndexOf` method returns `-1` if `x` does not contain `criteria.Author`. So, I am looking is th index of `criteria.Author` different from `-1`.

Comment: But my question is returnData contains an author property and title property, by doing option 2, is it searching in both the properties for the value of crieria.Author?

Comment: @user2206329 Oh, sorry. I forgot to add `Author` after x. It was giving compile-time error.Now, it is Ok.

Comment: You cannot do a case insensitive compare by using `ToLower` because it will fail in Turkish: [Does Your Code Pass The Turkey Test?](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html)

Answer (score 6):

```
returnData = returnData.Where
        (x => x.Author.IndexOf(criteria.Author, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
```

It will make no additional string allocation at all.

I assumed it's LINQ to Objects query.

Comment: Use Linq's `Contains` overload which takes in an `IEqualityComparer<string>` instead, and I will upvote.

Comment: Using LINQ `Contains` on `string` will make it work on each char separately. It would need `IEqualityComparer<char>`. What comparer would you provide to make it work?

Comment: You are right. I thought we were searching a collection of strings.

Comment: If he used Linq-to-objects, why would he have `.AsQueryable()` in the beginning?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen If he had a DbContext why would he call `AsQueryable()` at all?